# Specific Composer path always defaults (jumps) back to server root

Tags: php, drupal, cpanel

How do I invoke the "composer self-update" command that doesn't default back to the server root which I don't control?
I have a Drupal 7 (live) & a Drupal 10 (for dev) install on the same server. When I specify the composer path (to Drupal 10) in cpanel terminal it defaults back to server root and the old composer ver and doesn't allow update. Therefore when I invoke "php.composer.phar in the Drupal 10 vendor/composer path returns "command not found." Can't add modules or update D10. I don't use composer for Drupal 7.

I tried going to the Drupal 10 install (in cpanel terminal) into the vendor/composer folder and using the php.composer.phar command. Hoping to see this composer for the Drupal 10 install to upgrade to new ver. but the path keeps automatically jumping back to server root.

---

I see "everywhere" that I should run the command from the new Drupal 10 install folder and bypass root composer.

As I said, the command automatically defaults back to the server root, over which I have no control and it requires updating which I can't do.

The new Drupal 10 install has a composer folder in it. However, as I said, "php.composer.phar" command in the vicinity (from the new install root, or the sites/vendor) still defaults back to the server root. Consequently, no composer update. . .no adding Drupal 10 modules or updates.

Comment: What about transferring the `composer.phar` on the server and run it with `php composer.phar`? *into the vendor/composer* You have to run composer from the root of your project, not from the folder that store the dependencies.